# Últimas postagens blog wordpress em outro site em PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estou precisando colocar em uma landingpage que ta em HTML os últimos posts de um blog que está em Wordpress, consegui um código na internet que tras os posts mais não consigo definir quantos posts vão aparecer e nem pegar a imagem do post. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Se tiver algum outro código que faça isso também.

Obrigado.

```
<?php
            $url = 'http://blog.empresa.com.br/category/empresa/feed/';
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            $item = '1';


            if($xml !== false){
            echo '<div class="blog">';
            foreach($xml->channel->item as $node){
            printf('<h5><a href="%s">%s</a></h5>', $node->link, $node->title);
            printf($node->description);
            }
            echo '</div>';
}?>
```

Comment: nesse exemplo você esta carregando o feed gerado pelo worpress, uma opção é configurar isso no wordpress. Outra opção é manipular melhor esse xml pra controlar nesse loop a quantidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionei, há varias formas de resolver isso usando PHP

Ou mesmo usando componentes prontos para wordpres ou outros CMS's

Como não foi especificado se o site destino foi construído usando usando algum CMS, segue um exemplo usando `DOMDocument` no PHP

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://blog.empresa.com.br/category/empresa/feed/');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5; //Quantidade que deseja exibir
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Postado em '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: a LandingPage não está utilizando nenhum CMS, apenas HTML e CSS, coloquei o PHP que postei apenas pra puxar os últimos posts do blog que está em wordpress

Comment: caso você queira exibir sem a necessidade do PHP, é possível fazer isso usando apenas JS tbm https://gist.github.com/juanbrujo/3a71489572e5677fcec7e14676aa66e2

Comment: conseguei com esse código php que vc postou acima, só fiz alguamas alterações para limitar o número de caracteres da descrição, por exemplo. Obrigado.